# Insert wait in VS2008 web test

Tags: visual-studio-2008, delay, webtest

How can I insert time wait value in web test in Visual Studio 2008 test edition?

I have recorded a web test that I want to use in Load test. Now I need to put some time delay between pages in web test.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use "think times" to control the wait time between requests.

Your recorded tests will have think times included (based on how long it took you to click between pages), but they can be overridden by options within the loadtest itself.

Select the properties of your scenario to change the "Think Profile", change the "Think Time" property of the webtest to add a wait.

Comment: I was researching and found "Think Time" property, I was putting values of 50 and more but it does not wait, maybe it expects milliseconds so I will try that first time this morning. 

thanks a lot.

Comment: No, it is in seconds. Check the your load test is configured to use the wait times.